# Is Mobile UI design (almost) entirely different from Desktop / Laptop UI design?

Tags: desktop, web-design, mobile-ui

My question stems from a piece of JavaScript I wrote for the desktop which uses a ctrl-click to activate a certain feature. Now that I'm thinking of porting to mobile, I can't conceive of how to translate this to mobile. But the question I'm asking here is at a higher level: Does UI design for mobile require an (almost) totally different mind set / set of design skills? Is the best answer that I really need to take a course or find / hire an expert to figure out how to design for mobile?

Thank you for your insights on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes.

Modern design has to be adaptive to create a coherent customer journey. When designing a UI across multiple platforms, 'Mobile First' is a common way to work. Start from a mobile design and make it adaptive so it can fit to desktops and tablets.

I would say you should look for online tutorials about mobile first design. If after trying the tutorials you find it's not for you, then you can think about hiring someone to help.